# Non-orientable surface in math meme

Tags: soft-question, non-orientable-surfaces

Here is a math meme:

[image]

Text translates to

> Guys, this artist turned the disney princesses into **non-orientable surfaces** aaaaaa I'm crying

I recognize the [Möbius strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) and the [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle), but what about the red one (down left)? I've never seen it. What is its name?

Comment: You can find illustrations of non-orientable surfaces [here](https://www.euler-math-toolbox.de/Programs/Examples/Non-Orientable%20Surfaces.html).  I think the picture is a bit ambiguous, but I figure it's a realization of the projective plane.

Comment: Assuming they are using the most well-known non-orientable surfaces, there is really only one option left after the two you did identify.

Comment: Looks like Boy's surface, a particular immersion of the projective plane in $3$-space.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely [Boy's surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy%27s_surface) which I like to call a wonky [cruller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruller).